# How to make dataTable resized automatically after reloading data?

Tags: jquery, css, html, datatable

When there is no data then the `dataTable` looks like this :

[image]

The last header has a small width. After reloading , the `dataTable` has the last header the same width:

[image]

But when I inspect the page then the last header has a larger width :

[image]

So how to make the `dataTable` to be automatically adjusted like in the last photo after being reloaded ?

Answer (score 2):

you can added following code blog into datatable.js

```
  $(window).on("resize", function () {
        table.columns.adjust()
           .responsive.recalc();
})
```

Comment: I use `jquery.dataTables.min.js` so there is no way to modify it.

Comment: @pheromix - even though the expression is ambigious, this answer is not about modifying the source but about using the dataTables API. Try add the snippet to your script.

Comment: I added `list_commandes.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();` in my code but I got error on console : `TypeError: list_commandes.columns.adjust(...).responsive is undefined`. I use jQuery dataTable version 1.10.6

Comment: @pheromix, yes - reponsive is a plugin, do it without it -> `table.columns.adjust()`, try do it in a `initComplete` callback ... When you not have any code we can debug or try out, the only thing we can do is to give you suggestions based on guesses and encourage you to try the suggestions out.

Comment: how can I call it in the `initComplete` option ? I cannot get the returned of DataTable from there !